# Can an azcopy job be resumed from a different machine or location?

Tags: azure, azcopy

**Issue**

I have an azcopy job running, copying a 200gb directory from local to an Azure file share. I need to stop this job and resume it later from either:

a) Different PC, same location.

b) Same PC, different location.

My question is will resuming the azcopy job work using the same SAS token(not expired) from a different machine at a later time? Or as mentioned, will that same SAS token work to resume the azcopy job from the current PC, but from a different location/network.

**azcopy jobs resume command**

> azcopy jobs resume [jobID redacted]

I cannot find anything the documentation that specifically says it will not work. But I'm not finding anything assuring me it will work.